# rgl plot3d plotting points (spheres) and connecting them with single line

Tags: r, rgl

I am using the `plot3d` function from the `rgl` package. I have generated spheres using xyz co-ordinate data and I want to connect them with single line.

Here is my code:

```
file=read.table("input.txt")
df=data.frame(x=file[,1],y=file[,2],z=file[,3], color=file[,4])
plot3d(df$x, df$y, df$z, col=df$col,  type='b')
```

where b is for points joined by lines

If I use s instead of b it is giving me only spheres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the documentation in `?rgl`, type="b" isn't supported.

> type: For the default method, a single character indicating the
>             type of item to plot.  Supported types are: 'p' for points,
>             's' for spheres, 'l' for lines, 'h' for line segments from
>             ‘z=0’, and 'n' for nothing.  For the ‘mesh3d’ method, one of
>             'shade', 'wire', or 'dots'.  Partial matching is used.

I would try `plot3d()` followed by `lines3d()`.